# CakePHP2 & Twitter OAuth: Invalid / expired Token

Tags: php, cakephp, twitter, oauth

I was using OAuth consumer component 2.1.0 and CakePHP 2.4.4. 
and I want to implement "sign in With Twitter".

Here is the code.

app/Controller/Component/OAuthConsumers/TwitterConsumer.php:

```
<?php
class TwitterConsumer extends AbstractConsumer {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
    }
}
?>
```

app/Controller/UserController.php:

login:

```
    $requestToken = $this->OAuthConsumer->getRequestToken('Twitter', 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/users/oauth_callback');

    if ($requestToken) {
        $this->Session->write('twitter_request_token', $requestToken);
        $this->redirect('https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=' . $requestToken->key);
    } else {
        // an error occured when obtaining a request token
    }

    $this->autoLayout = false;
```

callback:

```
    $requestToken = $this->Session->read('twitter_request_token');
    $accessToken = $this->OAuthConsumer->getAccessToken('Twitter', 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token', $requestToken);

    if ($accessToken) {
        $profile = json_decode($this->OAuthConsumer->get('Twitter',$accessToken->key, $accessToken->secret, 'https://api.twitter.com/1/account/verify_credentials.json'));
        // Add user
        $this->User->update(
            Array(
                "user_id" => $profile['id_str'],
                "username" => $profile['screen_name'],
                "oauth_token_key" => $accessToken->key,
                "oauth_token_secret" => $accessToken->secret,
            )
        );
        $this->data['User']['access_token_key'] = $accessToken->key;
        $this->data['User']['access_token_secret'] = $accessToken->secret;

        if ($this->Auth->login($this->data)) {
                $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect()/*'/'*/);
        } else {
                $this->redirect('/users/login');
        } 
        die("OK");
    } else {
        die("ERROR");
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Error'));
        $this->redirect('/users/login');
    }
```

I try to sign in and redirected from twitter to my callback. But said:

```
Notice (8): OAuthRequest::from_consumer_and_token(): The script tried to execute a method or access a property of an incomplete object. Please ensure that the class definition "OAuthToken" of the object you are trying to operate on was loaded _before_ unserialize() gets called or provide a __autoload() function to load the class definition  [APP/Controller/Component/OAuthConsumerComponent.php, line 532]
Notice (8): OAuthSignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1::build_signature() [http://php.net/oauthsignaturemethod-hmac-sha1.build-signature]: The script tried to execute a method or access a property of an incomplete object. Please ensure that the class definition "OAuthToken" of the object you are trying to operate on was loaded _before_ unserialize() gets called or provide a __autoload() function to load the class definition  [APP/Controller/Component/OAuthConsumerComponent.php, line 342]
```

And I added some code to app/Controller/Component/OAuthConsumerComponent.php:

```
private function doRequest($request) {
    if ($request->get_normalized_http_method() == 'POST') {
        $data = $this->doPost($this->url, $request->to_postdata());
    } else {
        $data = $this->doGet($request->to_url());
    }

    var_dump($data);
```

And said:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<hash>
  <error>Invalid / expired Token</error>
  <request>/oauth/access_token</request>
</hash>
```

How to solve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you check the value of the $requestToken variable in your callback method?

Comment: $requestToken value is: `object(__PHP_Incomplete_Class)#4 (3) {
  ["__PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name"]=>
  string(10) "OAuthToken"
  ["key"]=>
  string(42) "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  ["secret"]=>
  string(41) "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
}`
`

Comment: I think you have to add `App::uses('OAuthConsumerComponent', 'Controller/Component');` to the top of your controller.

Answer (score 1):

Solved by myself.

login:

```
if ($requestToken) {
    $this->Session->write('twitter_request_token', serialize($requestToken)); // Added serialize
    $this->redirect('https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=' . $requestToken->key);
}
```

callback:

```
$requestToken = unserialize($this->Session->read('twitter_request_token')); // Added unserialize
$accessToken = $this->OAuthConsumer->getAccessToken('Twitter', 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token', $requestToken);
```

to work well.

Thank you for comments!